# Sql query to find rating?

Tags: mysql, sql, rating

In my application I'm storing reviews given by users into `mysql`.

Now I have to find rating based on reviews.I am storing review like "food quality,Service,Atmosphere,Value", all have values between 1 to 5.

How can I find rating based on these values.

My table structure is

FoodQuality  Service Atmosphere  Value  RestaurantId 
1                3      2          4        1

Comment: An example of your data and the result you try to achieve, would help!

Comment: As you've given no actual info, the only answer that I could come up with is: "retrieve database values, calculate rating, show rating".

Comment: what is your calculation for rating? is it average of all reviews? is it something else? you need to be more clear

Comment: Ok you have a table of four ratings, RestaurantId. By rating you mean the Average(FoodQuality+Service+Atmosphere+Value) per RestaurantId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want rating per restaurant id, and because you didn't specify what do you mean by rating

```
SELECT RestaurantId
, SUM(FoodQuality+Service+Atmosphere+Value) rating1 -- the sum of total rating
, AVG(FoodQuality+Service+Atmosphere+Value) rating2 -- the average of total rating, max 20
, AVG((FoodQuality+Service+Atmosphere+Value)/4) rating3 -- the average of average rating, max 5
FROM table
GROUP BY RestaurantId
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some naive solutions in SQL, but I would recommend that you read this article: http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html and try to implement such a rating somewhere directly in your code.

That said a naive solution could be to say 4 and 5 are positive (for example):

**Pseudocode:**

`myrating = (SELECT rating FROM reviews
WHERE rating == 4 OR rating == 5) AS positivratings / (SELECT * FROM reviews) AS totalrating`

Answer (score 0):

Give us some tables structure. You can use the `[AVG()][1]` function. For further details give the tables structure please.

```
SELECT products.*, AVG(r.value) AS product_rating FROM products p LEFT JOIN ratings r ON p.id = r.product_id GROUP BY p.id
```

Considering that `products` is the table that you have ratings for and `ratings` is the table you hold the ratings in, `ratings.value` being the field that contains the value of the rating gaved.

Comment: ReviewId,ReviewerName,FoodQuality(float),Service(float),Atmosphere(float),Value(float)

Comment: Your comment is not very helping - however, I gave you a query that computes an average rating - try to map the tables from my example to your table structure :)

Answer (score 0):

Exactly you have to provide us the table details like there may be ratings per user then you have to use group by clause and AVG() mysql function to find rating per user.